# How can I check if a Google VM instance has already credentials for gcloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, gcloud-cli

In order not to call every time:

```
gcloud auth login
```

which would interrupt a script for user input

I would like to see if a user is already authenticated (any user) and only if no user, then to call `gcloud auth login`.

I would love a more elegant/reliable solution than scraping the output of `gcloud auth list`. Something like a `ping` that fails or succeeds if there is an account already AND the account has the right to do the thing. Maybe a `--dry-run` option?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Google Compute Engine VMs [are already authenticated](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#service_running_in_compute_engine) with credentials, which the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/cloud-client-libraries) automatically use (via [Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials)) when making api calls.

Answer (score 5):

Being logged in means having account property set. You can extract it via

```
gcloud config list --format='value(core.account)' 2>/dev/null
```

You can also use

```
gcloud auth list --format='value(active_account)' 2>/dev/null
```