# How to get the active authenticated gcloud account?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, verbosity

Using `gcloud auth ...` you can add or remove accounts used during the `gcloud` commands.

Is there a way to get the active account without `grep`-ing and `awk`-ing?

`gcloud auth list` is good for humans but not good enough to a machine. I want a cleaner solution.

`gcloud config list account` also shows me to verbose output:

```
Your active configuration is: [default]

[core]
account = service@<my_project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173114/how-can-i-check-if-a-google-vm-instance-has-already-credentials-for-gcloud

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
gcloud config list account --format "value(core.account)"
```

This would tell you:

```
Your active configuration is: [default]

service@<my_project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

To also avoid the active configuration message, you can redirect the stderr to `/dev/null`:

```
$ gcloud config list account --format "value(core.account)" 2> /dev/null
service@<my_project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

It would be nice if `--verbosity` would also work in this case to remove the `info` message. That would mean:

```
$ gcloud config list account --format "value(core.account)" --verbosity error
```

Any Googlers out there that can post a comment if this is a reasonable feature/bug request/report?

Comment: Alternatively use `gcloud auth list --filter=status:ACTIVE --format="value(account)"`. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/list

Comment: I've been running into issues with core/account not always being set.  Luís Bianchin's alternative approach of checking the auth list directly has proven to be more reliable.  It also has the added bonus of not printing a new line character if nothing is found.

Answer (score 30):

This also seems to work

```
gcloud config get-value account
```

Answer (score 9):

Both of these commands below will give the same result:

```
$ gcloud config get-value account
$ gcloud config list --format 'value(core.account)'
```

But when you want to set the account to be activated externally then it can be done with [the json key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! $(gcloud config get-value account &> /dev/null) ]]
then
    GCP_SA_KEY=<json credential key>
    GCP_ACCOUNT=service@<my_project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
    if [ -z $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ]
    then
        echo $GCP_SA_KEY > google-app-creds.json
        export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$(realpath google-app-creds.json)
        gcloud auth activate-service-account $GCP_ACCOUNT --project=<my_project> \
        --key-file=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
    fi
fi
```

Ouput will be like this

```
$ bash /path/to/the/above/file
Activated service account credentials for: [service@<my_project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com] 

To take a quick anonymous survey, run: 
  $ gcloud alpha survey

$ gcloud config get-value account
service@<my_project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: For those wanting to check if there are no active account, be aware that there is a minor difference between the output of these two commands: `gcloud config get-value account`
will return `(unset)` whereas `gcloud config list --format 'value(core.account)'` will return an empty output.

Answer (score 2):

Open gcloud console then run this below command, it work for me
***gcloud auth list***

Comment: The original question states, "`gcloud auth list` is good for humans but not good enough to a machine. I want a cleaner solution."

Answer (score 0):

The gcloud command is generally meant for humans to consume, rather than machines.

What are you trying to do? Generally speaking, if you need to auth programatically, you would use [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#application_default_credentials) and (for example) the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable, which the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/cloud-client-libraries) grab auth information from.