# How do I get the email name of the current user retrieved via default credential fetching

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcp-iam

I am not using a JSON key. I use the default credential loading mechanism that is used when you create any new client.

But what means is there to reflect on the current creds?

```
import google.auth
creds, project = google.auth.default()

# I can get the project id
print(project)

# I can get the oauth stuff
print(creds.client_secret)
print(creds.client_id)
```

But how do I get the email name of the user or Google service account that is currently active?

I tried this

```
print(creds.service_account_email)
```

But it returns an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'service_account_email'
```

This is suppose to be a property of the class.

I want to get the email name of the user or google service account.

## Edit

Related to this post: [Programmatically get current Service Account on GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65821436/programmatically-get-current-service-account-on-gcp)

From an example in that post, is there a way to get the *user's* email name if it's not a GSA?

```
import google.auth

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()

if hasattr(credentials, "service_account_email"):
  print(credentials.service_account_email)
else:
    print("WARNING: no service account credential. User account credential?")
```

Comment: Review the different credential classes. They have different properties and features. `google.auth.default` uses ADC to locate credentials. Some credential types only provide an access token and not the underlying credential properties.

Comment: I cannot find on Stack Overflow or GCP docs a definitive answer like "If you're authenticated using XYZ method (e.g., `Application Default Credential`, user account credential, etc.), then forget about retrieving the email -- it cannot be done (or show a sample code snippet of how it could be done.)" All the answers I am reading are narrowly scoped to `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` but doesn't give definitive answers to other scenarios.